# Javascript - Multiple onclick elements for different actions

Tags: javascript, html, loops, onclick, repeat

I am trying to figure out how to make this code significantly cleaner. I've tried multiple things but nothing seems to work.

```
toggle1.onclick = function() {
    var div = document.getElementById('toggle-content1');
    if (div.style.display !== 'none') {
        div.style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("arrow1").className = "arrow-right";
    }
    else {
        div.style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById("arrow1").className = "arrow-down";
    }
};

toggle2.onclick = function() {
    var div = document.getElementById('toggle-content2');
    if (div.style.display !== 'none') {
        div.style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("arrow2").className = "arrow-right";
    }
    else {
        div.style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById("arrow2").className = "arrow-down";
    }
};

toggle3.onclick = function() {
    var div = document.getElementById('toggle-content3');
    if (div.style.display !== 'none') {
        div.style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("arrow3").className = "arrow-right";
    }
    else {
        div.style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById("arrow3").className = "arrow-down";
    }
};
```

If anyone has any tips or learning resources that I can look at I would really appreciate some assistance! From what I understand, I need to pull the number somehow and then attach it into the toggle function?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var toggle1 = document.getElementById('toggle-switch1');
var toggle2 = document.getElementById('toggle-switch2');
var toggle3 = document.getElementById('toggle-switch3');

function handler(divId) {
    var div = document.getElementById(divId);

    div.style.display = div.style.display !== 'none' ? 'none' : 'block';
};

toggle1.onclick = handler.bind('toggle-content1');
toggle2.onclick = handler.bind('toggle-content2');
toggle3.onclick = handler.bind('toggle-content3');
```

or

```
var toggle1 = document.getElementById('toggle-switch1');

var switches = {
    'toggle-switch1': 'toggle-content1',
    'toggle-switch2': 'toggle-content2',
    'toggle-switch3': 'toggle-content3',
};

toggle1.parentElement.onclick = function(event) {
    if (switches[event.target.id]) {
        var div = document.getElementById(switches[event.target.id]);
        div.style.display = div.style.display !== 'none' ? 'none' : 'block';
    }
}
```

or you can specify on toggle-switch1 and toggle-switch2 and toggle-switch3 appropriate target names in data-switchTarget attribute, i.e. toggle-content1 for toggle-switch1, toggle-content2 for toggle-switch2 and toggle-content3 for toggle-switchTarget, e.g.:

```
<div id='toggle-switch1' data-switchTarget='toggle-content1'>...</div>
```

and code for that will be:

```
var toggle1 = document.getElementById('toggle-switch1');

toggle1.parentElement.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target.dataset.switchTarget) {
        var div = document.getElementById(event.target.dataset.switchTarget);
        div.style.display = div.style.display !== 'none' ? 'none' : 'block';
    }
}
```

upd: you have just updated question, so in that case you can use:

```
var toggle1 = document.getElementById('toggle-switch1');

var switches = {
    'toggle-switch1': {content: 'toggle-content1', arrow: 'arrow1'},
    'toggle-switch2': {content: 'toggle-content2', arrow: 'arrow2'},
    'toggle-switch3': {content: 'toggle-content3', arrow: 'arrow3'},
};

toggle1.parentElement.onclick = function(event) {
    if (switches[event.target.id]) {
        var div = document.getElementById(switches[event.target.id].content);
        var isDivDisplayed = div.style.display !== 'none';

        div.style.display = isDivDisplayed ? 'none' : 'block';
        document.getElementById(switches[event.target.id].arrow).className = isDivDisplayed ? 'arrow-right' : 'arrow-down';
    }
}
```